# Trying to pull from multiple tables and multiple columns within tables

Tags: sql

I have tried this query to pull up multiple tables and columns it works but comes back blank. 
select * from onshore.contracting where code between 18789 and 18798;
select * from onshore.safety_incident where code between 18789 and 18798;

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where is there an example of the input and expected output. SO is not a coding service

Comment: The answer to your first question is pretty easy.  Yes.

Comment: I tried but it brought back blank data saying no rows selected. (select * from onshore.contracting where code between 18789 and 18798;
select * from onshore.safety_incident where code between 18789 and 18798;)

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Answer (score 0):

For your immediate problem, the following SQL will work if you really want ***all*** the data:

```
select * from onshore.contracting where code between 18789 and 18798;
select * from onshore.safety_incident where code between 18789 and 18798;
... and so on.
```

These tables probably have different columns so you need a separate select statement for each one.

If you are going to do more with SQL then it really would be worthwhile to learn it.  There is a free resource here: https://www.w3schools.com/sql, my contribution is at http://www.thedatastudio.net and there are many others.  It is a bit dangerous to use SQL without understanding it.

Comment: Thank you! I will try this and definitely look at the training. I agree it's very confusing and not a language I understand yet. Thanks again